# UIRefreshControl + AFNetworking crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, afnetworking-2, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using AFNetworking 2.x and this UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking category,  have a weird problem using a UIViewController with a UITableView as a property, I add a UIRefreshControl with this particular code

```
CGRect frame = self.mytableView.bounds;
frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
UIView *refreshBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
refreshBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239/255.0f green:239/255.0f blue:244/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
[self.mytableView insertSubview:refreshBackgroundView atIndex:0];
[self.mytableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(getAlertList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.mytableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.h causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, when I have a call for my webservice and the user do a segue (the task its not finish), the task continue calling the UIRefreshControl from my dead VC, i have a strong reference for the property self.refreshControl.

The trace on the error leave to this part of the code in AFURLSessionManager.h on the Method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(__unused NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

exactly on this lines:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AFNetworkingTaskDidCompleteNotification object:task userInfo:userInfo];
});
```

I open a issue to AFNetworking an @matt (AFNetworking creator and maintainer) response was: "Your UIRefreshControl is being deallocated before the task finishes, causing a selector to be sent to an incorrect target. Be sure to keep a strong reference to the control to ensure that it's not released prematurely. " Something that i already know.I already use Instrument to detect the zombie object and all appears to be the UIRefreshControl, any ideas to solve this problem ???

Other advice or comment i had form @matt (AFNetworking creator and maintainer) was "It's the responsibility of the developer to either keep a reference to the control or cancel the associated task before performing the segue. " . I already try to cancel the task before the segue but it's the same problem.

If someone have a idea to do that or have a solution for this problem i would be very happy to listen.

Thx

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm asking because I am running into the same issue - without AFNetworking though but similar. Trying to keep a strong ref around but that doesn't seem to fix the issue here if the VC is deallocated before the fetch is done.

Comment: same crash here!.... any solution?

Comment: I am also facing same issue...